# Changing the Name of a File Selected in FileDialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I am trying to make an application which takes a file from your computer, renames that file with variables from 4 different combo boxes and then uploads it to an FTP server.

I have gotten everything working except the renaming part....
what i am trying to do is this.
`slectedFile.pdf` would become `combobox1_combobox2_combobox3_combobox4.pdf`
The file path is stored in a variable named `FileName` i know how to update FileName with the combobox values, but does it keep the original Path?

How would i go about doing this?

This is the code i have so far.
IP_box, User_Box and Pass_box are the textboxes for the appropriate server information.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(IP_Box.Text.ToString), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(User_Box.Text.ToString, Pass_Box.Text.ToString)
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Dim file() As Byte

        Try
            System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try


        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
        strz.Close()
        strz.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Function OpenDialog()
        Dim FD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        FD.Title = "Selecteer een bestand"
        FD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        FD.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        FD.FilterIndex = 2
        FD.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Filename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FD.FileName)
        End If
    End Function
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict`.  Where is the code to try what you describe? Use `Path.Combine()` to create the new filename and rename it.   `Filename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FD.FileName)` does nothing because (from MSDN) `The file name includes both the file path and the extension.`

Comment: oke, i changed Filename to this:

`Filename = System.IO.Path.Combine()`

according to MSDN it need 1 or 2 string parameters, i believe this is used to split the Path and the Filename, correct?
what would i enter as parameters?

My guess to update it i would do this:

`Filename = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "_" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString & "_" & ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString & "_" & ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString & ".pdf"`

although..... im pretty sure i'm wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your subroutine, you try to retrieve the file; you incorrectly use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FD.FileName)` as `FD.FileName` *already* provides the full file name.

In order to rename the file to your desired name, you need to firstly evaluate the values of each ComboBox, of which can be done as a loop:

```
Private Function enumerateCheckboxes(ByVal path As String)
    Dim fName As String
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf Control Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(Control, CheckBox).Checked) Then
            fName += CStr(Control.Name) + "_"
        End If
    Next
    fName = path + fName.Substring(0, fName.Length - 1) + ".pdf"
    Return fName
End Function

Public Function OpenDialog()
    Dim FD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    FD.Title = "Selecteer een bestand"
    FD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    FD.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    FD.FilterIndex = 2
    FD.RestoreDirectory = True

    If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim Filename As String = FD.FileName
        Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
        Filename = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "\"), Len(Filename))
        Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
        Return Filename
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenDialog()
End Sub
```

If I test with a file from the desktop:

[image]

However now we *might* possibly have an issue that the file does not exist, thus the program will crash. To fix this, we can quickly rename the file for the upload, and rename it back when it's finished.

The complete code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim originalFile As String

    Public Function OpenDialog()
        Dim FD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        FD.Title = "Selecteer een bestand"
        FD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        FD.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        FD.FilterIndex = 2
        FD.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Filename = FD.FileName
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            Filename = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "\"), Len(Filename))
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            Return Filename
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(IP_Box.Text.ToString), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(User_Box.Text.ToString, Pass_Box.Text.ToString)
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Dim file() As Byte

        Try
            Filename = OpenDialog()
            System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        FileSystem.Rename(originalFile, Filename)
        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
        strz.Close()
        strz.Dispose()
        FileSystem.Rename(Filename, originalFile)
    End Sub

    Private Function enumerateCheckboxes(ByVal path As String)
        originalFile = path
        Dim fName As String
        For Each Control In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf Control Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(Control, CheckBox).Checked) Then
                fName += CStr(Control.Name) + "_"
            End If
        Next
        fName = path + fName.Substring(0, fName.Length - 1) + ".pdf"
        Return fName
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i tried changing it to use ComboBoxes and SelectedItem.ToString, but this just gave me errors. 

`A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Could you maybe give me a hint or show me how to do this for the comboboxes?

And does it also permanently change the file name?

Comment: Little problem here, i used you code, saw that it might throw an error, used a Catch/Try on:

`Try
            fName = path + fName.Substring(0, fName.Length - 1) + ".pdf"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try`

and it came back with this: "object reference not set to an instance of an object." the file i selected was a new and empty .txt file